# webbrowser in C#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I've created a web browser in C#
And I can send a url, and get a reply and display the page on the allpication,
But how do I parse the reply string ?

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    string UrlText;
    string DocText;

        UrlText = "https://www.ancestry.co.uk/";

        webBrowser1.Navigate(UrlText);
        //webBrowser1.DocumentText(DocText);
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string DocText;
        //DocText = webBrowser1.DocumentText(DocText);
        //webBrowser1.DocumentText(DocText);
    }

    public string webbrowser1_DocumentText { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what is it what you want to do?? what is it that you want to parse? can you give an example?

Comment: `DocumentText` returns _"the HTML contents of the page displayed in the WebBrowser control."_ - is that not what you want?

Comment: Look into HTML Agility Pack for parsing html https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com

Comment: Are you talking about parsing the HTTP 200 response, and server-side headers, cookies, etc?